# Performance decreasing when the pool size of c3p0 incresed

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

My application is connecting to MySql database using c3p0 connection pool. Properties are given below

```
hibernate_c3p0_max_size=30
hibernate_c3p0_min_size=1
hibernate_c3p0_acquire_increment=1
hibernate_c3p0_idle_test_period=300
hibernate_c3p0_max_statements=0
hibernate_c3p0_timeout=360
hibernate_c3p0_initialpoolsize=1
hibernate_c3p0_maxpoolsize=30
hibernate_c3p0_minpoolsize=1
```

With this configuration we were able to use 80 users for test and after 45 minutes it crashed. So to improve the performance I increased the max and max_pool_size to 60 and min and min_pool_size to 15 but the result was shocking, application stopped responding at 5 minutes. Then I changed min and min_pool_size to 1 then application stopped responding at 8 minutes. Then I changed the max and max_pool_size to 30 and the application worked for 1 hour for 60 users, even though at 45 minutes it went to peak but managed somehow. Why the performance is going down when the pool size is increased???    What all things I should take care to get the max performance?

Below is the error it was giving when it crashed

```
 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@dbf2e57 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor142.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2159)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor115.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor142.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:958)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
```

Comment: Too little information. How does it crash? Are you sure it’s the pool size (probably not). You might find it interesting to also read this article by the authors of HikariCP (currently the best JDBC pool implementation). https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: @Strelok updated with error log. Thanks for the link let me go through it.

Comment: Please post exception messages as text (in a code block), not as a screenshot. Make sure to include the full exception stacktrace. The problem could be something exceeding the MySQL configuration of maximum connections. It may also suggest that maybe you aren't correctly closing connections (which returns them to the pool).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in the log it just repeating the same and I do close the conections.

Comment: I would expect an underlying exception for the cause of the failure to connect, not just the "Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up" (I might be wrong though, I don't regularly use MySQL).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel updated..

Comment: Most important part _"MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections"_, this suggests the connection limit (`max_connections`) on your MySQL server is too low, or that there are problems with releasing connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174258/discussion-between-anoop-ll-and-mark-rotteveel).